# Publish-subscribe pattern vs. visibility of UI

Tags: javascript, store, publish-subscribe

In my current SPA I'm keeping all data in a centralized store (state) whose actions trigger state mutations and publish certain pubSub events.

My UI logic is organized in different views (functions) which when called draw needed UI elements(, cache them), attach UI events and subscribe view specific UI logic to above mentioned pubSub events.

**The idea:** User fires UI events which call business logic that may or may not change the state and UI automatically updates according to those changes.

**The problem:** Different views might subscribe to the same store event, thus it can happen that callbacks are being executed for UI that's not existing at that time.

**The question:** Should I always unscubscribe all subscription of a view when view is changed OR is there a better way of doing it?

*No frameworks/libs involved, mainly for the learning purpose.*

Ps. Since I'm still new to those patterns I'm thankful for any piece of advice that may help to improve my concept.

Comment: Some code demonstration will be helpful to circle around the exact problem. Try making a codepen/fiddle

Comment: Didn't think it would be neccessary, but sure, I'll add some asap.

Comment: Yes, you should unscubscribe all subscriptions of a view when view is changed. This is how it's done usually.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, you should unscubscribe all subscriptions of a view when view is
>   changed. This is how it's done usually.

...as of Wiktor Zychla's comment. Thanks a lot!